# Monit running script as non-root user getting "permission denied"

Tags: bash, shell, permission-denied, monit

I am using Monit to ensure one of my applications is always running. Monit runs as root but my goal is to run the application as "myuser" and not as root. So I use the following configuration:

```
check process myprocess with pidfile "/home/myuser/monitoring/myprocess.pid"
    start program = "/home/myuser/scripts/myprocess.sh start"
    as uid 1000 and gid 1000
    stop program = "/home/myuser/scripts/myprocess.sh stop"
    as uid 1000 and gid 1000
```

Now when I login as myuser, navigate to `"/home/myuser/scripts"` and run ./myprocess.sh start , the application starts with no issues.

However when I let monit do it, the program does not start and logs show `permission denied` for a `mkdir` function in the sh file.

Isn't monit supposed to run it just like I would from shell since I specified uid and gid 1000 (which I got from the shell command `id`)? Did I miss anything in my configuration?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Comment: give a try to [immortal](https://immortal.run/post/run.yml/) `immortal -u www your-command`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fixed it by specifying the absolute path in the file/directory I was trying to modify in the script.